# How to switch the position of two buttons randomly؟

Tags: kotlin

I want to switch the positions of the buttons when we press the toggle button. Buttons are repositioned randomly. I tried a lot but was not successful. So if anyone knows how but randomly

```
   val btnOne = findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonOne) as Button
    val btnTwo = findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonTwo) as Button

    val posOneX = btnOne.x
    val posOneY = btnOne.y

    val posTwoX = btnTwo.x
    val posTwoY = btnTwo.y

    btnOne.x = posTwoX
    btnOne.y = posTwoY

    btnTwo.x = posOneX
    btnTwo.y = posOneY
```

Comment: What do you mean by randomly? If there are two items and you exactly switch them, that's determinant behavior with no randomness. Anyway, you will have to work with the ViewGroup(s) that contains the views to be able to work with their positions relative to each other.

Comment: You could use ``Random.nextBoolean()`` as an ``if`` condition to decide whether to do the swap at all, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found the solution

```
 b4.setOnClickListener {
     


            var arswap = arrayListOf<Button>(b1, b2, b3);
            var randomPos: Int = 0;


            fun swap(b1: Button, b2: Button) {
                var tempPosition = Point(b1.x.toInt(), b1.y.toInt())
                b1.x = b2.x;
                b1.y = b2.y;

                b2.x = tempPosition.x.toFloat();
                b2.y = tempPosition.y.toFloat();
            }

            var totalItems: Int = 3; // total number of items

            for (i in 0..totalItems/3 ) {

                randomPos = ((Math.random() * arswap.size).toInt());
                var randomItem =  ((Math.random() * ((totalItems / 2) - 1)) + ((totalItems / 2) + 1));


                swap(arswap[randomPos], arswap[randomItem.toInt()])
            }
       

    }
```